# analogWrite not set 0V

Tags: arduino, esp8266

For testing I use Wemos D1 mini R2 ESP8266 connected via USB to PC
I'm trying to turn on and off an LED connected to a pin on the module.
I use this code, but when it reaches the second for, the LED does not turn off completely (it remains voltage on the pin).

```c++
void setup() {
  pinMode(D3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);

  for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++){
    analogWrite(D3, i);
    delay(10);
  }

  for (int i = 255; i > 0; i--){
    analogWrite(D3, i);
    delay(10);
  }

  delay (2000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LED doesn't turn off completely because in your second loop your duty cycle never reaches `0`.

Thereof, change your second loop condition to `i>=0`